How to concatenate two dataframes of one row each without generating NaN
I have two dataframes:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n=10

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": 1.0,
        "B": pd.Timestamp("20130102"),
        "C": pd.Series(1, index=list(range(n)), dtype="float32"),
        "D": np.array([3] * n, dtype="int32"),
        "E": pd.Categorical(["test", "train"] * int(n/2)),
        "F": "foo",
    }
)

i_f = ['A', 'B']
o_f = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df[i_f].values, columns=i_f).reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df[o_f].values, columns=o_f).reset_index(drop=True)

df1 and df2 are dataframes with the same number of rows, and different columns. Now I want to select a row i in df1, a row j in df2, and obtain a single dataframe of a single row, which has the columns from df1 and df2. I do:
i = 3
j = 2 
df_curr = pd.concat([df1.iloc[[i], :], df2.iloc[[j], :]], axis=1)

However, what I get instead is a dataframe with two rows, and with NaNs:
print(df_curr)
#      A          B    C    D     E    F
# 3  1.0 2013-01-02  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
# 2  NaN        NaT  1.0    3  test  foo

Instead, I need
       A          B    C    D     E    F
#    1.0 2013-01-02  1.0    3  test  foo

How can I get it?

This question is similar to: How to merge two dataframes without getting additional rows?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JonSG it's not similar at all, and as a matter of fact the answers to that question don't work here. Did you even try them?

Your get different rows because your slices have different indices (2 and 3), thus concat keeps them on different rows.
Since you want a single row, concat as Series, then reshape:
i = 3
j = 2 
df_curr = pd.concat([df1.iloc[i], df2.iloc[j]]).to_frame().T

Or reset_index after slicing to force both slices to have 0 as index, but this is less elegant IMO:
df_curr = pd.concat([df1.iloc[[i], :].reset_index(drop=True),
                     df2.iloc[[j], :].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

Output:
     A                    B    C  D     E    F
0  1.0  2013-01-02 00:00:00  1.0  3  test  foo


Your approach didn't work as your slices had different indices (2 and 3), thus pandas assigns them to different rows. Using Series avoids this, since they will be concatenated in one dimension. In the second approach, resetting the index sets both indicew to 0 therefore they will end up in the same row.

This is what I just explained. concat keeps the rows on their original index, which are different here. If you had used j = 3 they would have been on a single row. My workarounds bypass this index alignment.

you're right, that's why I deleted the comments. There's an issue with your solution, though! Passing through a Series means that now the dtype of all the columns is object, which is wrong and creates issues for me later on. Maybe I should try the second approach (resetting indices)?

you can check by yourself with df_curr.dtypes

The second approach doesn't change the dtypes for me, you could always restore them with df_curr = df_curr.astype(df1.dtypes). The way you create df1/df2 loses the dtypes (check df1.dtypes/df2.dtypes).

yes, I meant that the second approach doesn't change the dtypes (only the first one). We're good! Answer accepted
